# Using command prompt to run an elevated command prompt without Popup

Tags: command-prompt

So, I am trying to make a startup batch script that runs as an administrator during windows startup.

I have my script here:

```html
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 3"
```

The only problem I am facing here is that every time the batch script gets executed, I always get a prompt to enter administrator password. Is there any additional way to remove this popup and directly run the command?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your powershell command, try `runas`:

```
runas /savecred /user:Administrator "fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 3"
```

The first time it runs, you will be asked to provide the Administrator password at the command line. After that point, it *should* run without any prompt because of the `/savecred` flag. So run it once before putting it in your startup script.